# How can i use ListPicker with Page that use App Bar?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listpicker, appbar

When I try to use "App Bar" with page that had "ListPicker" , ListPicker disappearing ?!

List Picker:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker   
x:Name="listPicker"   
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}"  
FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}"  
Header="Sound" 
FullModeHeader="CHOOSE AN ITEM"  
CacheMode="BitmapCache"
/>
```

App Bar :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar/save.png" Text="Add" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you be a bit more specific about what your problem is? It's not very clear.

If you're talking about the ListPicker not showing up, it's most likely an issue with the rest of your XAML and how you inserted the items. To my knowledge there's nothing wrong with the code you've put up.

Comment: The "ListPicker" Works 100% 
But when i add code above for "App bar" to my page that already contains "ListPicker" , ListPicker disappearing  !

Comment: this article discusses the same problem :
[link](http://seanbriscoe.info/2011/01/17/the-case-of-the-wp7-listpicker-and-the-disappearing-applicationbar/#comment-179)
but the solution is for old Version of ListPicker .

Comment: Oh, I have no clue why that is happening. Should definitely file a bug.

Can you try setting `ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"` on your ListPicker and see if that helps? That's the same as setting `ItemCountThreshold="0"` in the solution link you have.

Comment: I think both are using something in common ( maybe interface or something else ..i don't know) , it's bizarre  !